# Change color of a QString in the QTextEdit

Tags: qt, user-interface

Does anyone here know how can I find a `QString` in the `QTextEdit` and change the color of it?

Comment: @user3528438 Nah. There is a function called `setTextColor()` that I can call. The problem is how to color just the QString i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`QTextEdit::find()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#find) + 
[How to highlight a string of text within a `QTextEdit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14889286/4149835)

See also: [`QSyntaxHighlighter`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsyntaxhighlighter.html#details)

Comment: I have already done that. But I want to change the color of the text not highlight it. Thanks anyway!!!

Comment: @DomenJesenovec, then you need to use this answer about html formatting: [QTextEdit with different text colors (Qt / C++)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6934270/4149835)